# Is there a package to resize everything?

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to find something like this:

```
\documentclass{my-own-class}
\usepackage[24pt]{resize}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

Here, `24pt` is the size of the `\normalsize`. I expect all sizes (`\small`, `\large`, etc.) to be updated accordingly. This is something similar to the `11pt`, `10pt`, and `12pt` options of the `article` package, but with a much larger variety. Are you aware of such a package?

Comment: you can use the `extarticle` class with size options up to 20pt you may also want a package such as `\usepackage{lmodern}` to get fonts at a wider range of sizes

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm looking for a package, not a class (because I use my own class, not `article`).

Comment: extsizes package (which is the same code as extarticle, more or less, but if it is your own class you don't need anything at all just implement whatever sizes options you want)

Comment: you could try `\usepackage[fontsize=24pt]{scrextend}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer this is exactly what I was looking for. Please, post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to its documentation, the `fontsize` package is your friend:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} % we want fully scalable fonts

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fontsize=24pt]{fontsize}

\setlength{\textheight}{4cm} % just to make a smaller picture

\begin{document}

Hey! It works!\footnote{Yes, it does.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614114/is-there-a-package-to-resize-everything#comment1534311_614114),

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\usepackage[24pt]{resize}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\changefontsizes{24pt}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```